# Capture requests/network traffic

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to capture the the requests made by javascript.

I tried with `net.lightbody.bmp -> browsermob-core -> 2.1.5`, but after I import this in maven, the chromedriver no longer starts and I get an error.

This is the code which I have:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "data/chromedriver-91.0.4472.19.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //the error appears here when browsermob is imported

try{

    driver.get("https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/sync/xhttp-messages.html");
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    driver.quit();
}
```

Without importing `browsermob`, it works.

After import, I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;

at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.asMap(ChromeOptions.java:292)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at com.test.core.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

How I can fix this error? Or how I can capture the requests made by javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrowserMob Proxy uses old version of guava library. It looks like guava defined in `browsermob` dependencies are closer to the root in your dependency tree that that is in Selenium dependencies.

To solve that you can add new guava version dependency to your **root** `pom.xml`. The latest one is:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```